# Prototyping web-application models

Tags: database, model-view-controller, model, prototyping

What tools/practices do you recommend for rapidly getting a working model of a database/MVC-model working? I could start hacking away at the framework of my choice and add tables as I go, but I prefer to get the structure fleshed out a little before I hit the keyboard.

I could just use pen-and-paper, but it can be a bit crude to rapidly do things. I'd like something 1 step above - perhaps a diagramming tool that allows me to model relationships. UML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and use the [WebRatio](http://www.webratio.com) tool. It's model driven and it's based on the [WebML](http://www.webml.org) notation (soon to become an OMG standard under the name of [IFML](http://www.ifml.org)).
The tool is free for non commercial purposes and personal use, you can download it for free.

[Disclaimer: I'm with Politecnico di Milano and WebRatio, and among the inventors of WebML/IFML]

Answer (score 0):

SQL Power Architect is free and open source, good for designing your database model. It can forward or reverse engineer to most databases.

http://www.sqlpower.ca/page/architect

Java Spring Roo is useful for quickly setting up a RESTful web service or server-generated HTML MVC system.

Gnome Dia is a good open source diagramming tool that can do UML, and has plugins to write Java or SQL for you:

https://live.gnome.org/Dia